# what is the best way to create a custom admin panel in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to create a custom admin panel in Django. what is the best way to do that ? I have found some ways :

- use some packages to customize that like [jet](https://jet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [django-material-admin](https://github.com/MaistrenkoAnton/django-material-admin), [django-cms](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/), [django-jazzmin](https://django-jazzmin.readthedocs.io/)

- create an `admin` app with `python manage.py startapp admin` and develop that with my own `views` and `templates`

is there any better way to do that ?

I want to know what professionals do. I would be grateful if you could introduce a clue or a helpful article.

Answer (score 1):

actually, we create our theme from scratch by overriding every single component and style class in Django.

Comment: where can i find admin components and styles in django ? any documentation? @MahmoudNasser